# How to expose PostgreSQL OpenShift/Kubernetes service listening on 5432 to the external world?

Tags: openshift, kubernetes

It seems that external IP address can be assigned while creating a service in Kubernetes/OpenShift. Is there a possibility to use OpenShift routes for the same so that I don't have to manage/get externally routable IP address. Is it possible to expose a Postgres OpenShift/Kubernetes service listening on 5432 as a OpenShift route listening on 5432?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NodePort feature of services to expose a port on every node in the cluster.  You *can* assign a floating VIP to one of your nodes and set the service ExternalIP field on the service.